# Visual Basic 6.0 ActiveReports Print Dialog Printer Button

Tags: vb6, activereports

[image]Hi

I have a weird question.

I have a legacy VB6 application which I am maintaining. I am using ActiveReports control to print reports from this app. we are using this application since years, but when one of our clients upgrade his windows with Windows 8, he notice that the Printer button disappear from Print Dialog box. I am including the pictures of dialog in windows XP and windows 8 environment.

Please note this is fine in Windows 7 environment.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Heaps of thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be a hugely stupid question, but does he have more than 1 printer installed?

Comment: Yes he has more than one printer installed.

Comment: `Printer` button is missing since Vista. Read `Remarks` section on the `PageSetupDlg` API function here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646937(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a dialog controlled by the operating system and not ActiveReports (technically it could disabled the printer button it does not, as you can see in Win7). That button only appears when there is more than one printer installed.  So my guess is the Win8 box has one printer and win7 has more than one.

Comment: No, in Windows 8 Box, there is more than one printer installed.

Comment: Why don't you try creating a simple VB6 test application to show a Page Setup dialog and run it on both machines and see it's behavior. I don't remember for sure, but I think you can show that dialog with the "Common Dialog" control in VB6.
Another option might be to show the same dialog with Wordpad on both machines. At least this will help you understand if it is related to AR or VB or the OS.